# Python given implicit equation, find points on that equation?

Tags: python, math, geometry, vtk, iges

Context: Convert an `.iges` to `.vtk`.

I have the following equation `Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2+Dx+Ey+F=0` representing a conic section.

The parameters `A~F` are given. **I want to find points on the conic section**, so that I can connect them with lines, and make a mesh.

The reason I need the points instead of just using `matplotlib Ellipse` is because I'm creating a mesh not a plot.

It is in 3 dimension space, but I first get points on xy plane, and use affine transformation to send it to 3 dim.

Question: `How do I find points given an implicit equation?`

Comment: I don't know what's the best approach for general implicit equations. But for conic sections, consider a Bresenham-like algorithm. A web search for "Bresenham algorithm conic sections" finds some resources, e.g: https://alexander.agathoscompany.com/publications/CAG98.pdf , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm , and https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Algorithms-of-Conic-Generation-Pitteway/b1f3d1baf7500cfbfeeeade0fa3b8d70146064d7 . Good luck and have fun.

Comment: Conic sections with an `xy` term are rotated (not in standard position). You can change coordinate system, calculate your points, and change back to the original. Something of the form `X.T() @ AQ @ X` as described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_representation_of_conic_sections).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid spending too much time on this, I wrote some code that seems to handle general ellipses. It can be expanded for other conics, depending on what is needed.
The code takes in the coefficients of a general quadratic equation of an ellipse and a number of desired points to be generated on the ellipse and generates a set of points on the ellipse.

```py
import numpy as np

def equation(conic, points):
     '''
     equation of a conic with coefficients 'conic' 
     applied to a matrix number_of_points x 3 whose each row is the coordinates
     of each point
     '''
     c = np.array(conic)
     x = np.array([points[:,0]**2, points[:, 0]*points[:,1], points[:,1]**2, points[:,0], points[:,1], np.ones(points.shape[0])])
     return c.dot(x)
 
def equation_to_matrix(eq):
    '''
    eq[0]*x**2 + eq[1]*x*y + eq[2]*y**2 + eq[3]*x + eq[4]*y + eq[5] = 0
    '''
    return np.array([[2*eq[0],   eq[1],   eq[3]],
                     [  eq[1], 2*eq[2],   eq[4]],
                     [  eq[3],   eq[4], 2*eq[5]]]) / 2

def solve_quadratic(a, b, c):
    '''
    solves
    ax^2 + bx + c = 0
    '''
    D = b**2 - 4*a*c
    D = np.sqrt(D)
    return (-b-D)/(2*a), (-b+D)/(2*a)

def eigen2(S):
    '''
    solves the eigen-decomposition problem
    for a 2x2 symmetric matrix
    '''
    k1, k2 = solve_quadratic(1, -S[0,0]-S[1,1], S[0,0]*S[1,1] - S[0,1]*S[1,0])
    u1 = np.array([-S[0,1], S[0,0]-k1, 0])
    u1 = u1 / np.sqrt(u1.dot(u1))
    u2 = np.array([-u1[1], u1[0], 0])
    return np.array([k1, k2]), np.array([u1, u2, np.array([0,0,1])]).T

def center(conic_matrix):
    center = np.linalg.solve(conic_matrix, np.array([0,0,1]))
    return center/center[2]
    
def find_rotation_and_translation(conic_matrix):
    '''
    conic = c[0]x^2 + c[1]*xy + c[2]*y^2 + c[3]*x + c[4]*y + c[5] = 0
    the result is rotation U such that U.T C U = diag
    '''
    k, U = eigen2(conic_matrix)
    U[:,2] = center(conic_matrix)
    return U, k

def find_transform(conic):
    C = equation_to_matrix(conic)
    U, k = find_rotation_and_translation(C)
    C = (U.T).dot(C.dot(U))
    C = - C / C[2,2]
    k = np.array([1/np.sqrt(C[0,0]), 1/np.sqrt(C[1,1]), 1])
    return U.dot(np.diag(k))

def generate_points_on(conic, num_points):
    '''
    conic = [c[0], c[1], c[2], c[3], c[4], c[5]]
    coefficients of the qudaratic equation:
    conic: c[0]x^2 + c[1]*xy + c[2]*y^2 + c[3]*x + c[4]*y + c[5] = 0
    result is the affine transformation (scaling, rotation, translation)
    that maps the unit circle to the ellipse defined by the coefficients
    'conic' 
    '''
    cos_ = np.cos(2*np.pi* np.arange(0, num_points)/ num_points)
    sin_ = np.sin(2*np.pi* np.arange(0, num_points)/ num_points)
    U = find_transform(conic)
    points = np.array([cos_, sin_, np.ones(num_points)])
    return ((U.dot(points)).T)[:,[0,1]]

'''
Test:
'''

'''
Ellipse with equation whose coefficients are in the list E.
The ellipse has semi-major axes 2 and 1,
it is rotated 60 deg from the horizontal,
and its center is at (1, 4)
'''   
E = [ 3.25,  -2.59807621, 1.75, -23.40192379, 6.89230485,   39.35769515]


'''
U maps points from unit circle to points on E
'''
U = find_transform(E)

print(U)

'''
the set of points on the ellipse E
'''
p = generate_points_on(E, num_points = 20)
print(p)


'''
check that the points p lie on the ellipse E
'''
print(equation(E, p).round(10))

'''
plot
'''
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot()
ax.plot(p[:,0], p[:,1], 'ro')
ax.set_aspect('equal')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The code below handles the case of a hyperbola. It largely adapts the code from [here](https://scipython.com/blog/direct-linear-least-squares-fitting-of-an-ellipse/)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def equation_to_matrix(eq):
    '''
    eq[0]*x**2 + eq[1]*x*y + eq[2]*y**2 + eq[3]*x + eq[4]*y + eq[5] = 0
    '''
    return np.array([[2*eq[0],   eq[1],   eq[3]],
                      [  eq[1], 2*eq[2],   eq[4]],
                      [  eq[3],   eq[4], 2*eq[5]]]) / 2

def hyp_params_from_general(coeffs):
    # get the matrix of the quadratic equation
    Aq = equation_to_matrix(coeffs)

    # get the matrix of the quadratic form A33
    A33 = Aq[:2, :2]

    # determinant of A33
    detA33 = np.linalg.det(A33)

    if detA33 > 0:
        raise ValueError('coeffs do not represent a hyperbola: det A33 must be negative!')

    # get the center
    x0 = -np.linalg.det(np.array([Aq[:2, 2], Aq[:2, 1]]).T) / detA33
    y0 = -np.linalg.det(np.array([Aq[:2, 0], Aq[:2, 2]]).T) / detA33

    # The semi-major and semi-minor axis lengths (these are not sorted).
    # get discriminant of the conic section
    delta = np.linalg.det(Aq)

    # get the eigenvalues
    k1, k2 = np.linalg.eigvals(A33)

    k1isk2 = np.isclose(k1/k2, -1)

    ap = np.sqrt(abs(delta/k1/detA33))
    bp = np.sqrt(abs(delta/k2/detA33))

    # Eccentricity.
    fac = np.sqrt((Aq[0, 0] - Aq[1, 1])**2 + Aq[0, 1]**2)
    if delta < 0:
        nu = 1
    else:
        nu = -1
    e = np.sqrt(2*fac/(nu*(Aq[0, 0] - Aq[1, 1]) + fac))

    # slope of the asymptotes
    if Aq[0, 0] == Aq[1, 1] and k1isk2:
        m1 = 0.
        m2 = np.nan
    else:
        m1 = Aq[0, 0]/(-Aq[0, 1] - np.sqrt(-detA33))
        m2 = Aq[0, 0]/(-Aq[0, 1] + np.sqrt(-detA33))

    # Sort the semi-major and semi-minor axis lengths but keep track of
    # the original relative magnitudes of width and height.
    width_gt_height = True
    if ap < bp and not k1isk2:
        width_gt_height = False
        ap, bp = bp, ap

    # The angle of anticlockwise rotation of the major-axis from x-axis.
    if Aq[0, 1] == 0:
        phi = 0 if Aq[0, 0] < Aq[1, 1] else np.pi/2
    elif Aq[0, 0] == Aq[1, 1]:
        phi = np.pi/4 # would divide by zero and arctan(inf) -> pi/4
        if m1 > 0 and m2 > 0:
            width_gt_height = True
    else:# Aq[0, 0] > Aq[1, 1]:
        phi = np.arctan(2*Aq[0, 1]/(Aq[0, 0] - Aq[1, 1])) / 2

    if not width_gt_height:
        # Ensure that phi is the angle to rotate to the semi-major axis.
        phi += np.pi/2
    phi = phi % np.pi

    return x0, y0, ap, bp, phi, e, m1, m2, width_gt_height

def get_hyperbola_pts(params, npts=100, tmin=-1, tmax=1):
    x0, y0, ap, bp, phi, m1, m2 = params

    # A grid of the parametric variable, t.
    t = np.linspace(tmin, tmax, npts)

    # points
    x = x0 + ap * np.cosh(t) * np.cos(phi) - bp * np.sinh(t) * np.sin(phi)
    y = y0 + ap * np.cosh(t) * np.sin(phi) + bp * np.sinh(t) * np.cos(phi)

    # asymptotes
    ya1 = y0 + m1*(x - x0)
    ya2 = y0 + m2*(x - x0)

    return x, y, ya1, ya2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    coeffs = [1., 6., -2., 3., 0., 0.]

    x0, y0, ap, bp, phi, e, m1, m2, width_gt_height = hyp_params_from_general(coeffs)
    print('x0, y0, ap, bp, phi, e, m1, m2, width_gt_height = ', x0, y0, ap, bp, phi, e, m1, m2)

    x_, y_, ya1, ya2 = get_hyperbola_pts((x0, y0, ap, bp, phi, m1, m2), npts=250, tmin=-2, tmax=3)

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16, 9))
    ax.plot(x_, y_, marker='.', linewidth=0.5, c='r')
    ax.plot(x_, ya1, marker='.', linewidth=0.2, c='b')
    ax.plot(x_, ya2, marker='.', linewidth=0.2, c='b')
    ax.grid(True, linestyle='--')
```